# Is there a way to hidden facebook advertisements on application iframe?

Tags: facebook, facebook-application, facebook-graph

Probably it's not possible, but i need to confirm it.

If someone knows it, tell me please :)

thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure but I *think* questions about Facebook app belong on [Webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).